# Como verificar a presença de cada elemento de um vetor, linha por linha em uma matriz em R?

Tags: r

Suponha que eu tenha um vetor que vai de 1 a 10. Eu quero verificar de forma binária pra cada elemento do vetor se ele está presente na linha da matriz, sendo 0 para não presença e 1 para presença, independente do elemento repetir eu só contabilizaria 1 para ele.

Por exemplo, na primeira linha da matriz eu tenho `a[1,]= c(1,5,2,2,1)`. Assim, eu teria 0 para os elementos 3,4,6,7,8,9,10 e 1 para os elementos 1,2,5.

Answer (score 5):

A função `%in%` faz exatamente isso que é procurado. Seja a matriz `a` dada por

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 
              2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 
              3, 8, 9, 6, 7), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

E seja o vetor `v` com os elementos de 1 a 10:

```
v <- 1:10
```

Veja o que obtemos ao rodar o código abaixo:

```
v %in% a[1, ]
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Para converter `TRUE` e `FALSE` em 0 e 1, utilize a função `as.numeric`:

```
as.numeric(v %in% a[1, ])
## [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Para que este resultado seja aplicado em todas as linhas da matriz, utilize a função `apply`, com o parâmetro `1`, indicando que os cálculos serão feitos por linhas:

```
t(apply(a, 1, function(x) as.numeric(v %in% x)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
## [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
## [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1     0
```